# Match non variant values in enum in Rust

Tags: rust, enums, casting, pattern-matching, match

Let's say I have the following enums - mixing c-style assigned values and variant enums:

```
enum Command {
    Control(ControlSubcommand) = 0x00,
    Temperature = 0x02,
    Voltage = 0x04,
    ...
}

enum ControlSubcommand {
     Status = 0x00,
     DeviceType = 0x01,
     ....
}
```

I then pass it to a function when I try to deconstruct the given command to individual values. For a c-style command with a value directly assigned (Temperature, Voltage and so on) I want to get it's corresponding value - so 0x02, 0x04 and so on.

For the "variant" command (Control) I want to get the it's value and subcommand - so 0x00 with 0x00, 0x01 and so on.

I'm trying to write the following match construct to do so:

```
match command {
    Command::Control(subcommand) => {
        println!("control command with subcommand {}", subcommand as u32);
    }
    simple => {
        println!("simple command {}", simple as u32);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that technically `simple` is still a `Command` which is a non-primitive type, so `as` cast does not work with it. Even though the variant case was already handled before and will not appear in `simple`, Rust still disallows me from performing a cast.

Is it possible to somehow fix this code without changing the enum layout?

- using if-let syntax doesn't help.
- simple `as` cast doesn't work

Comment: impl `From<Command> for u32` is an option?

Comment: _"without changing the enum layout?"_ -- do you mean the layout in memory or the type defintion?

Comment: The easiest way is to simply match every element.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

@BiagioF I'm just starting with Rust, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something - but how the trait implementation will distinguish the types? I suspect I'll need to implement practically the same match construction in the end.

Comment: @PeterHall I meant the type definition. I think that this issue is solvable by splitting the enum into 2 groups - simple commands (u8) and extended commands (u8, u8) - and then do pattern-matching based on the group.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman it may work with the current state of code - but imagine if I add 10-15 more commands in the future....

Comment: Just do it. You can encapsulate it in a function of course. It is better than the alternative of having unsafe code in your project. The compiler will also optimize it away. You can have a macro generate it if you really want, or there are dozens of variants or the code changes constantly. Though to be honest, even in these cases I'd just hand-write it, unless you have a lot of such enums.

Comment: @RomanLuitko for simple code, avoid unsafe. A simple solution (if it fits your case) might be: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a53b4bb9aa45ee0538e0b9684f2620c

Comment: I was mostly searching for some syntax line that I'm missing. I'm definitely not considering unsafe code or some evil hacks for such simple task.

Answer (score 2):

There is no safe way to do that. If the enum is `#[repr(integer)]` (which it must be to be able to define the discriminants).

But you can read the discriminant using unsafe code, [as explained in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html#accessing-the-numeric-value-of-the-discriminant):

```rust
#[repr(u32)]
enum Command {
    Control(ControlSubcommand) = 0x00,
    Temperature = 0x02,
    Voltage = 0x04,
    // ...
}

enum ControlSubcommand {
    Status = 0x00,
    DeviceType = 0x01,
    //  ....
}

fn get_discriminant(v: Command) -> u32 {
    match v {
        Command::Control(v) => v as u32,
        // SAFETY: Because of `#[repr(u32)]`, the first field is the `u32` discriminant.
        _ => unsafe { *(&v as *const Command as *const u32) },
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `*<*const Command>::cast(&v)` be preferrable over 2x `as` casting? (not sure actually)

Comment: @cafce25 This is subjective (your variant is full of sigils). Although to be honest I didn't consider this option.

Comment: To add to the bikeshed, nowadays I prefer `(&v as *const Command).cast::<u32>().read()`.